# Convert XML elements into a comma delimited string in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, delimiter

I have these elements in my XML file here:

```
    <Applications>
        <Application>Base Operations</Application> 
         <Application>Development Screen</Application> 
         <Application>eStat</Application> 
         <Application>EStat Rate Quote Poller</Application> 
         <Application>ETA Alert Agent</Application> 
         <Application>File Maintenance</Application> 
         <Application>Fuel Optimization Agent</Application> 
         <Application>FuelSourcingModule</Application> 
         <Application>Operations Reporting</Application> 
         <Application>Order Entry</Application> 
         <Application>PB GP Stand Alone</Application> 
         <Application>PB Rating Engine</Application> 
         <Application>PS Scheduler</Application> 
         <Application>Reports</Application> 
         <Application>Settlements</Application> 
         <Application>System Administration</Application> 
         <Application>TMW Backoffice</Application> 
         <Application>TMW CRM Right</Application> 
         <Application>TMW Operations</Application> 
    </Applications>
```

How do I convert each of these into a list that looks like this: `Base Operations, Development Screen, eStat, etc.`?

Comment: what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
[XML]$xml = @"
<Applications>
        <Application>Base Operations</Application> 
         <Application>Development Screen</Application> 
         <Application>eStat</Application> 
         <Application>EStat Rate Quote Poller</Application> 
         <Application>ETA Alert Agent</Application> 
         <Application>File Maintenance</Application> 
         <Application>Fuel Optimization Agent</Application> 
         <Application>FuelSourcingModule</Application> 
         <Application>Operations Reporting</Application> 
         <Application>Order Entry</Application> 
         <Application>PB GP Stand Alone</Application> 
         <Application>PB Rating Engine</Application> 
         <Application>PS Scheduler</Application> 
         <Application>Reports</Application> 
         <Application>Settlements</Application> 
         <Application>System Administration</Application> 
         <Application>TMW Backoffice</Application> 
         <Application>TMW CRM Right</Application> 
         <Application>TMW Operations</Application> 
    </Applications>
"@

[String]::Join(",",$xml.Applications.Application)
```